# How to output Hadoop EL counters from streaming Map Reduce job triggered by Oozie?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hadoop-streaming

I am triggering a streaming MapReduce job using Oozie, for which I would like to collect the following Hadoop EL constants:

MAP_IN: Hadoop mapper input records counter name.

MAP_OUT: Hadoop mapper output records counter name.

REDUCE_IN: Hadoop reducer input records counter name.

REDUCE_OUT: Hadoop reducer input record counter name.

I see that these can be accessed using

${ hadoop:counters('mr-action')[RECORDS][REDUCE_OUT]}

However, I have no idea how to get these values to be output back to either the screen via STDOUT or to a file in HDFS on the server from where I'm launching the Oozie workflow.
I've tried passing these values to a shell action and then echo / append to a file, but I believe this is being handled on the data nodes and so I'm not able to see that output.  I've also tried setting oozie.action.external.stats.write to true, as one thread suggested, and then calling

oozie job -info  -verbose

but I still don't see these counters showing up under an External Stats field.  Any suggestions of how to get these counters output will be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Before I was doing oozie job -info job-id -verbose which wasn't displaying external stats.  Key was to make following changes.

In workflow.xml file, under the action I want to collect counters for, add the following to the configuration:

```
<action name="mr-action">
    <configuration>
        <property>
            <name>oozie.action.external.stats.write</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
</action>
```

Then, after job is run, do the following in the command line:

oozie job -info job-id@mr-action -verbose

which gives me the counters I was looking for.